# Steampunk-inspired constructed world tips?

Tags: society, alternate-history, alternate-worlds

Nothing too complicated but what are some tips and tricks to consider when creating a steampunk-inspired conworld and the like?

Comment: Hello, newcomer! Just so you know, this forum is focused around a specific goal: That someone may ask a valid question, have it answered, and then anyone with that same question, however many years from now, can find that answer clearly articulated here. As such, you should be careful about how you phrase questions. You'll get used to it. I don't mean to beat you over the head with it or say that your question is wrong (it isn't), I've just seen new people get torn apart here because they don't understand things and wanted to inform you. (: 

All the best in your worldbuilding!!

Comment: Nice question albeit inappropriate as it violated one of the policy, that's no tipping!

Comment: Seems to me more suited to our sister site: [writing.se]. We can help you solve problems relating to the creation of the world, but style and genre seem to be on the writing side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. People who like steampunk tend to love victorian society. There's the rush of the industrial revolution changing society, the fancy dresses and clothes, the disruption as the old royalty and nobility are replaced by new merchants and businesses.
2. People like accessible tech. Modern computers are mostly black boxes with components too small to see. It's fascinating taking apart a clock or a windup toy and seeing how it works. Steampunk is fascinating for many because you have large flashy tech where you can see how it works with your own eyes.
3. There's a big vintage tech and antique element. People are fascinated by older technology which was much more visual and so including elements of that which make super science is interesting to people. People like the idea of DIYing tech and building crazy devices in a workshop. Mad geniuses should be the norm, not dedicated industrial factories.
4. Fantasy is optional. Arcanum, Frostpunk and Fallen London all explore some magic lurking alongside the steampunk as examples.
5. Class conflict is a very popular theme. Arcane, Bioshock infinite both explore the idea of an oppressive leadership which is rich and racist against their lessers and the war that results.

https://www.reddit.com/r/steampunk/top/?t=all

This should help with getting some of the popular themes and aesthetics as well.